# How to create Lambda versions with different EnvironmentOptions using CDK

Tags: python, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have created my Lambda function as part of my CDK stack in typescript

```
const dummy_lambda = new Function(this, 'dummy-lambda', {
  functionName: 'dummy-lambda',
  code: Code.fromAsset('../dummy-lambda/src'),
  handler: 'index.lambda_handler',
  timeout: Duration.seconds(900),
  runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
  role: snapshotRole,
  environment : {
    'region': props.env.region,
    'utility': props.Utility,
    'siteUrl' : props.siteUrl
  }
});
```

I want to create different versions of this lambda to be able to run it for different applications by changing the `siteUrl` and `Utility` EnvironmentOptions. However, `Version` doesn't take `environment` as props.

```
   const dummy_ver_ci =new Version(this, 'ci-dummy', {
  lambda: dummy_lambda,
  description: 'Version for CI app'
});
```

How can I create different versions and pass different `environment` values to each version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate Lambda Functions that would all use the same code.

A `Version` is a Lambda function at some point in time - each time you publish your function, a new version is created. This is not something that would fit this use case.